# What is the fastest way to generate dummy variables in R?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

What is the fastest way to turn factors into dummy variables in R?

I know of two alternatives: using `model.frame` and `model.matrix`, or the `fastDummies` package. In my non-exhaustive benchmarks, the former appears to be much more performant:

**Edit**:
I have updated the benchmarks below to incorporate Akrun's and Ben Bolker's suggestions from the comments:

```
library(fastDummies)

N <- 100000
x <- as.factor(sample(1:1000, N, TRUE))
y <- as.factor(sample(1:10, N, TRUE))
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

library(bench)
time <- 
mark(
    model.matrix(model.frame(~ -1 + x, data = df)), 
    Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(model.frame(~ -1 + x, data = df)), 
    t(Matrix::fac2sparse(df$x)),
    fastDummies::dummy_cols(df, remove_first_dummy = FALSE, remove_selected_columns  = TRUE), 
    iterations = 1, 
    check = FALSE
  iterations = 1, 
  check = FALSE
)
time$median
# 262.39ms  80.39ms 613.16ms   6.91s
```

Is there a potentially faster alternative to using `model.matrix(model.frame())`? Is `fastDummies` simply not as fast, or are there any scenarios in which I might want to use `fastDummies` if all I cared about was performance?

Comment: Sorry, I should rephrase my question: I was confused that `model.matrix()` seemed to outperform `fastDummies` in all my experiments - so my question is if `fastDummies()` simply isn't that fast?

Comment: If you want more faster option, perhaps `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~-1 + x,data=df, verbose = FALSE)` could be faster

Comment: or `t(Matrix::fac2sparse(df$x))`

Comment: maybe it would be worth asking the package authors [here](https://github.com/jacobkap/fastDummies/issues) ?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that and ask :)

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~-1 + x,data=df, verbose = FALSE)
```